# ORACLE : Assignment and Checking in same statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

In Oracle PL/SQL, can I do something like this :

```
if ( ( i = a ) = 3 )
```

that is - set variable `i` to `a` and then check if it is `3`.

thanks

Comment: that will require the value of i to be set before checking. What I want is to set i equal to a first. And then check if it is 3.

Comment: Realistically, no, you're not going to be able to assign and check the value in a single step.  You'd need a single step (which I'd argue to be the cleaner approach in a language where you could do both in one step).  If you're really determined, you could use a function that assigns a value to an OUT parameter and returns that value but I can't think of a situation where you'd want to do that.

Comment: You might be able to do something using object types, like `if i(a).something = 3`, where `i(a)` is a call of a custom constructor and `something` is an attribute of `i`. I haven't tested this though as I suspect it isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
set serveroutput on

declare
    i   number;
    j   number;
begin
    i   := 3;
    j   := 3;
    if ( ( i = j ) = 3 ) then
        dbms_output.put_line('Success');
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('No luck');
    end if;

end;
```

So I tried above code and below is the error I got.

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '='
```

So I understand that we can't do assignment and checking is same statement.

Comment: `( i = j )` returns Boolean TRUE. Therefore you can't compare with number. Alternate would be `(( i = j ) = (i = 3))`

Comment: Thanks @DamithJinasena. You are right. Although I am not sure whether OP wants to solve this way.

Comment: That is not doing any assignment of the value to i, which is what the OP requested.  This just does a double-comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course:

```
declare
  a number := 3;
  i number;
begin
  i := a; if i = 3 then dbms_output.put_line('i am so smrt'); end if;
end;
```

:)